# Create Wildcard Domains for emails as "Verified identities" - Amazon SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I created a web-application that agencies can use via white-label so my brand is 100% removed and replaced with theirs. I have a completely irrelevant primary domain they can use and they get a subdomain on that primary domain... we'll call it `defaulturl.com`. So their custom URL would be something like "**agency**.defaulturl.com"

I have everything working except I am trying to make emails coming from the application come from their custom domain. So I need to create some sort of "wildcard" verified identity in Amazon SES so these subdomains works.

I was able to get `*@defaulturl.com` to work, but this isn't their domain. I instead need something like `*@*.defaulturl.com`.

I've tried with no avail, is this possible?

Comment: When you create a new white label, use the AWS API to validate the subdomain. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#verifydomainidentity

Comment: I think that may be the solution. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does anyone know how this can be done in terraform? Thanks